# What type can I use to specify it inside <> brackets of ResponseEntity instead of using Object as a general type?

Tags: java

I'm following the [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html)

where I'm researching for a constructor as:

```
public ResponseEntity(@Nullable T body, HttpStatus status) {
   this(body, (MultiValueMap)null, (HttpStatus)status);
}
```

and I'm trying to find the correct type for the method in `return` operator.

As I see, it contains two parameters as:

1. `@Nullable T body` - the entity body
2. `HttpStatus status` - the status code

Based on it, my question is:

how do I need to specify argument for the constructor inside brackets `<>` in the method below:

```
@PutMapping
@Operation(summary = "Updating project")
public ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO> updateById(@RequestBody Project project) {
    logger.info("updateById() is calling...");

    if (project != null) {
        projectRepository.save(project);
        return new ResponseEntity<..., ...>("Updated successfully.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<..., ...>("Update failed.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

I've already tried to use:

1. `<ProjectDTO, HttpStatus>`
2. `<HttpStatus>`
3. `<ProjectDTO>` and so on, but I still don't fully understand what can I use if I want to return the answer for the user, but not to use `Object` as a type and to narrow the type in return of the method.

[image]

Everything instead of `Object` return me compile error in code.

If you need some more details I can provide you without any problem.

My `DTO` is:

```
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
public class ProjectDTO implements Serializable {

    public ProjectDTO(Project project) {
        this.name = project.getName();
        this.abbreviation = project.getAbbreviation();
        this.customer = project.getCustomer();
    }

    private String name;

    private String abbreviation;

    private String customer;
}
```

**UPD:**

if I use `ProjectDTO` as a type on the left side I'm receiving also a compile error as:

[image]

if I use `Object`, I don't have any issues, but can I narrow the type of the method below?

```
@PutMapping
@Operation(summary = "Updating project")
public ResponseEntity<Object> updateById(@RequestBody Project project) {
    logger.info("updateById() is calling...");

    if (project != null) {
        projectRepository.save(project);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Updated successfully.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Update failed.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Thank you in advance for your attention and smart ideas.

I appreciate any help with it.

Comment: `public ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO> updateById` tells the return type is `ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO>`.

Comment: The problem is `return new ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO>("Updated successfully.", HttpStatus.OK);` gives me compile error, if I correctly understand you.

Comment: `return new ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO>("Updated successfully.", HttpStatus.OK);` produces a compile error because "Updated successfully." is a String, not a `ProjectDTO`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments point out, you have a method returning `ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO>` but you are returning `ResponseEntity<String>`

The actual answer will depend on the architecture of your service:

Do you want the caller to know how the updated entity is? Then

```java
@PutMapping
@Operation(summary = "Updating project")
public ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO> updateById(@RequestBody Project project) {
    logger.info("updateById() is calling...");

    if (project != null) {
        ProjectDTO entity = projectRepository.save(project);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(entity, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ProjectDTO("","",""), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

with the above code, when the update is successful it will return a populated object, and an empty one in case of failure. If you want to show your string as in your code snippet, I'd recommend you do so in the service consuming from this API.

On the other hand, if you don't care about knowing the entity and instead wish to send back a message, then

```java
@PutMapping
@Operation(summary = "Updating project")
public ResponseEntity<String> updateById(@RequestBody Project project) {
    logger.info("updateById() is calling...");

    if (project != null) {
        projectRepository.save(project);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Updated successfully.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Update failed.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Take notice that I don't tell the created `ResponseEntity`-ies the type. That is because you already have it defined in the methods' signature. Actually, quality assurance tools like SonarQube will complain about it, not because is wrong, but because is not neccesary.

Answer (score 0):

Your method return type is `ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO>` and this is the type that you need to construct.

The return statement is therefore

```
ProjectDTO someProjectDTO = createProjectDTOFromProject(project);
return new ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO>(someProjectDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Or even shorter (since Java can correctly infer the type arguments):

```
ProjectDTO someProjectDTO = createProjectDTOFromProject(project);
return new ResponseEntity<>(someProjectDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
```

The first line is some pseudo code because I don't know how you create your ProjectDTO instances.

Comment: I've updated my question with `DTO` hope it helps a bit. Could you clarify, please, if I have  the construction:
`return new ResponseEntity<..., ...>("Updated successfully.", HttpStatus.OK);`

And the first argument on the right side is `String`, second `HttpStatus`, can I use something as an argument/-s on the left side instead of `Object`? if yes, am I correctly understand you, it should be `ProjectDTO` as in the declaration?